# How to unload older version of rlang package?

Tags: r, package

I've installed a newer version of "rlang" package (0.4.7).
When I did the library, it gave me error messages as follows:

> library(rlang)
> Error in value[3L] :
> Package ‘rlang’ version 0.4.5 cannot be unloaded:
> Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘rlang’ is imported by ‘tibble’, ‘pillar’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘lifecycle’ so cannot be unloaded

I then tried the detach() and unloadNamespace() functions, both gave me errors:

> detach("package:rlang", unload = TRUE, character.only = TRUE)
> Error in detach("package:rlang", unload = TRUE, character.only = TRUE) :
> invalid 'name' argument
> unloadNamespace("rlang")
> Error in unloadNamespace("rlang") :
> namespace ‘rlang’ is imported by ‘tibble’, ‘pillar’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘lifecycle’ so cannot be unloaded

How should I do then?

Comment: Restart your R session. Make sure not to run any code that loads the package before you try to update it.

Comment: In addition to what MrFlick said, you might also try installing the packages in just pure R instead of in RStudio if you're using it

Comment: Problem solved! MrFlick method worked fine. Thanks a lot both!

Comment: @Kai. Rstudio gives me the opportunity to restart when I try to load a new version of a previously installed package.